# Truncated action of Stasheff associahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, operads

I was reading [this](https://math.mit.edu/~ebelmont/operads-talk.pdf) introduction to operads in which the associahedron operad $\mathcal{K}$ is explained. In section 3 there is an explanation of a truncated action of this operad. Literally it says

> being homotopy associative is the same thing as saying there is an
>   action of just $\mathcal{K}(i)$ for $i ≤ 3$.

where homotopy associative means that there is a homotopy between the operations $\mu(\mu(-,-))$ and $\mu(-,\mu(-,-))$, where $\mu$ is a product.

However, if one has an action of the whole operad $\mathcal{K}$ then in particular there is a homotopy between both operations since any two bracketing of a product are homotopic (see the picture of $\mathcal{K}(4)$ in page 2).

I am having troubles to geometrically understand what is the difference between having an action of only $\mathcal{K}(i)$ ($i\leq 3$) and having an action of the whole operad. In the first case I believe that all the homotopies between any two bracketings of a product are the same, while on the second case there is a parametrized family of homotopies.

**Q:** Is my interpretation correct? Can someone show me an example of this difference?

Comment: I am not an expert, so you might want to take this with a grain of salt. But I think that the truncated action only means that there exists homotopies between the different bracketing, and the full action means that there are homotopies between those different homotopies, and that the space of such homotopies is contractible. This looks like a "homotopy commutativity vs homotopy coherence" kind of situation.

Comment: @RobinCarlier that would make sense, thank you